# First order PDE with method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ with two differential initial conditions, where one is the Heaviside step function $u(x,0)=1$ for $x>0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ for $x<0$; and the other one is its reflection where $u(x,0)=0$ for $x>0$ and $u(x,0)=1$ for $x<0$.

Can anyone share some steps on how to solve the problem by solving the two ODEs obtained from characteristics? Any help is appreciated!

Regards!

(And how to type hybrid functions here? Could express the initial condition clearer but don't know how to type it properly lol...)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @QuitMSE I've proceeded to getting the two ODEs, but solving them myself don't seem to obtain the correct answer..